# CSS not being included into rules for <div> element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML file (simplified)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>SineRider</title>
    <link href='App/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='veil' id='mobile-warning-veil' hide=true>
      <div class='string' id='mobile-warning-remarks'>
        <p>Sinerider is best played on wider screens.</p>
      </div>
      <button class='string button' id='mobile-warning-dismiss'>Nevermind, let me in</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

which as seen uses the following (again, simplified) CSS stylesheet

```css
#mobile-warning-veil {
    opacity: 1;
}

body {
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';

  color: #333;
  background: #fff;

  font-size: 18px;

  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.veil {
  position: absolute;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;

  background: white;
  pointer-events: all;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.veil[hide=true] {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

however, when I load the HTML file, the `mobile-warning-veil` still has opacity set to 0, and using the devtools I can see that the rules I defined have not been applied at all. I have tripled-checked the selectors and I am almost 100% certain that they're correct. What could be the reason for the rules to not apply here?

if you feel you need more context, [here](https://github.com/hackclub/sinerider/commit/acb2874370bc1edc92cfcee8c5fbb4c1cb39a1b1) you can see the full, unsimplified code

Comment: First you need to check that your style file is in the right folder/directory - are you seeing any errors in your browser dev tools inspect facility console? When that is sorted out you need to look at the specificity of the selectors you are using. An ID will always have greater weight than any collection of class and atrribute selectors. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked out the commit you shared.

*#mobile-warning-veil* has opacity 0 when width is greater than 600px due to below styling:

```
.veil[hide=true] {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and for width less than 600px, the following media-query is applied:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  #mobile-warning-veil{
    opacity: 1;
    color: #676767;
  }
}
```

What happens is the id selector is more specific than the attribute selector so when media-query is active, that styling is applied. Otherwise, the first one is. You need to keep the specificity of selectors in mind to get the desired result.

**Note:** I did have to remove the comment above media-query and only then did it start working. You can look into that too.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't close the `div` tag.
2. You need to add `!important` in your style.

I've marked both of them with comments in the code

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#mobile-warning-veil').setAttribute('hide', 'false');
})
```

```css
#mobile-warning-veil {
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.veil {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  background: white;
  pointer-events: all;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.veil[hide=true] {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  /* I added !important */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>SineRider</title>
  <link href='App/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='veil' id='mobile-warning-veil' hide=true>
    <div class='string' id='mobile-warning-remarks'>
      <p>Sinerider is best played on wider screens.</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- You didn't close the DIV tag -->
  <button class='string button' id='mobile-warning-dismiss'>Nevermind, let me in</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: however, this doesn't seem to address how the `#mobile-warning-veil` ruleset doesn't even appear on the devtools (and is therefore not applied as well): [image](https://i.imgur.com/YGgNY55.png)

Comment: also, you seem to have misplaced the div close; that's on me, but this solution doens't solve my issue here;

Answer (score 0):

The background-color of a div is white.

So opacity 1 is 100% color with no transparency.
It cover all with its background.

When the opacity is 0 (when hide), all another elements are displayed.

Close `<div>` after all to be container of others.

When it's close before the next div is covered all